# Remove leading zeros from single digit months in year-month values

Tags: r, lubridate, stringr, as.date

For year month vector: `year_months <- c('2021-12', '2021-11', '2021-02', '2021-01')`,
I try to use the following code to convert `year_months` to `c('2021Y12m', '2021Y11m', '2021Y2m', '2021Y1m')` :

```
format(as.Date(lubridate::ym(year_months)), "%YY%mm")

stringr::str_replace_all(format(as.Date(lubridate::ym(year_months)), "%YY%mm"), "-0?", "")
```

Out:

```
[1] "2021Y12m" "2021Y11m" "2021Y02m" "2021Y01m"
```

How could I remove the leading zeros from the single digit months? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gsub`:

```r
gsub("Y0", "Y", format(as.Date(lubridate::ym(year_months)), "%YY%mm"))
# [1] "2021Y12m" "2021Y11m" "2021Y2m"  "2021Y1m"
```

Or `stringr::str_replace_all`:

```r
stringr::str_replace_all(format(as.Date(lubridate::ym(year_months)), "%YY%mm"), "Y0", "Y")
# [1] "2021Y12m" "2021Y11m" "2021Y2m"  "2021Y1m"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `paste`, date format isn't of much interest and would just produce overhead.

```
sapply(strsplit(year_months, '-'), \(x) 
       paste(paste0(as.numeric(x), c('Y', 'm')), collapse=''))
# [1] "2021Y12m" "2021Y11m" "2021Y2m"  "2021Y1m"
```

Comment: Sorry, I  get an error: `unexpected input in "sapply(strsplit(year_months, '-'), \"`.

Comment: @ahbon You need to update your old R version or use `function(x)` instead of `\(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
format(as.Date(paste0(year_months, '-01'), format = '%Y-%m-%d'), '%YY%mm')
```

which will generate:

```
#"2021Y12m" "2021Y11m" "2021Y02m" "2021Y01m"
```

Comment: This does not seem like the expected output; OP asked to remove the leading zeros in months.

Comment: Thanks, but as @Maël commented, your code didn't remove leading zeros.